# PySimpleGUI: making Listbox elements selected by default

Tags: listbox, pysimplegui

I am new to PySimpleGUI and I am trying to drag and drop an Apple Music folder into the LISTBOX (creating a list of file paths). Is it possible to make the whole list of file paths selected by default as soon as the folder is dropped into the LISTBOX? Thanks in advance for any help.

I used the code here to enable drag&drop capability to the LISTBOX:
https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/3780#issuecomment-756789528

Maybe there are other elements more suitable for what I am trying to achieve.